# Convert this JSON format using JSON Converter

Tags: c#, json

I'm generating the below JSON format, could someone tell me how to convert this back to my class.

```
["Node1",{"DictionaryNode1_1":"NodeValue1","DictionaryNode1_2":"NodeValue2","DictionaryNode1_3":"NodeValue3"},["Node11",{"DictionaryNode11_1":"NodeValue1","DictionaryNode11_2":"NodeValue2","DictionaryNode11_3":"NodeValue3"},"Node12",null,["Node121",null,["Node1211",{"DictionaryNode1211_1":"NodeValue1","DictionaryNode1211_2":"NodeValue2","DictionaryNode1211_3":"NodeValue3"}]]],"Node2",null,["Node21","Node22"]]
```

[image]

How do i achieve this by using the below converter method.

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
}
```

Below is the class for conversion.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(TreeNodeConverter))]
public class SubTreeNode : TreeNode
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dicAttr;

    public Dictionary<string,string> dicAttr
    {
        get
        {
            return _dicAttr;
        }
        set
        {
            _dicAttr = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to complete almost any operations over JSON serialized strings. So for your sample, if i understand you properly, you just need to deserialize string to `Dictionary<string,string>` (or `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>>`...) type so here are some topics to consider:
- [Deserialize to Object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm)
- [Or you can deserialize to `dynamic` and do whatever you like after it (for **C# 4** and one of the **latest Json.NET** versions)](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)
- [Querying JSON with dynamic](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm)

Here is sample from Json.net with deserialization to [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx):

```
string json = @"[
  {
    'Title': 'Json.NET is awesome!',
    'Author': {
      'Name': 'James Newton-King',
      'Twitter': '@JamesNK',
      'Picture': '/jamesnk.png'
    },
    'Date': '2013-01-23T19:30:00',
    'BodyHtml': '&lt;h3&gt;Title!&lt;/h3&gt;\r\n&lt;p&gt;Content!&lt;/p&gt;'
  }
]";

dynamic blogPosts = JArray.Parse(json);

dynamic blogPost = blogPosts[0];

string title = blogPost.Title;

Console.WriteLine(title);
// Json.NET is awesome!

string author = blogPost.Author.Name;

Console.WriteLine(author);
// James Newton-King

DateTime postDate = blogPost.Date;

Console.WriteLine(postDate);
// 23/01/2013 7:30:00 p.m.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out JSON.NET. It has a very good documentation and it will certainly be helpful for all your needs for operating with json.

Here the link [Json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

And here the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)